# Looping through every script in a folder as a parallel job,

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a need to run scripts in the folders an parralel jobs.

Here is what my folder structure looks like:

```
.
├── quo1374
├── quo2147
├── quo1407
......
├── quo1342
│   ├── dist
│   │   └── v0.1.0-alpha
│   │       └── unix
│   │           └── mjolnir
│   ├── examples
│   │   ├── values-local-134217728-m4.2xlarge.yaml
│   │   
│   ├── remote_script.sh
│   └── run
│       ├── quo1342-134217728-m4.2xlarge
│       │   ├── quo1342-134217728-m4.2xlarge
│       │   └── quo1342-134217728-m4.2xlarge.sh
│       ├── quo1342-134217728-m4.xlarge
│       │   ├── quo1342-134217728-m4.xlarge
│       │   └── quo1342-134217728-m4.xlarge.sh
│       ├── quo1342-134217728-m5.12xlarge
│       │   ├── quo1342-134217728-m5.12xlarge
│       │   └── quo1342-134217728-m5.12xlarge.sh
│       ├── quo1342-134217728-m5.16xlarge
│       │   ├── quo1342-134217728-m5.16xlarge
│       │   └── quo1342-134217728-m5.16xlarge.sh
│       ├── quo1342-134217728-m5.24xlarge
│       │   ├── quo1342-134217728-m5.24xlarge
│       │   └── quo1342-134217728-m5.24xlarge.sh
│       ├── quo1342-134217728-m5.4xlarge
│       │   ├── quo1342-134217728-m5.4xlarge
│       │   └── quo1342-134217728-m5.4xlarge.sh
│       ├── quo1342-134217728-m5.8xlarge
│       │   ├── quo1342-134217728-m5.8xlarge
│       │   └── quo1342-134217728-m5.8xlarge.sh
│       ├── quo1342-134217728-m5.metal
│       │   ├── quo1342-134217728-m5.metal
│       │   └── quo1342-134217728-m5.metal.sh
│       ├── quo1342-134217728-t2.2xlarge
│       │   ├── quo1342-134217728-t2.2xlarge
│       │   └── quo1342-134217728-t2.2xlarge.sh
│       ├── quo1342-134217728-t3a.2xlarge
│       │   ├── quo1342-134217728-t3a.2xlarge
│       │   └── quo1342-134217728-t3a.2xlarge.sh
│       └── quo1342-134217728-t3a.xlarge
│           ├── quo1342-134217728-t3a.xlarge
│           └── quo1342-134217728-t3a.xlarge.sh
```

For example, the script `└── quo1342-134217728-m4.2xlarge.sh` runs one job.  This a subset of jobs I would like to run. I am trying to come up with a s ript that will take the content of `run/quo134*/quo1342-134217728*.sh` and run it as a seperate job, i.e. when activated, I would loop through each of the scripts in the folder , but the entire job would be held by a `&`. The reasoning behind this is that I have about 12 separate folders that look like this . I would love to run them in parallel. it is however important that the scripts within the folders are run sequentially.

Here is an attempt of what I trying to do . Although it does not work, I hope it add clarity to my question.

```
for f in *
do cd $f/run 
    for f in *.sh

      bash "$f" -H &
      cd ..
    done
done
```

I would appreciate any pointers on this.

### Update

The answers from [dash-o](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12098405/dash-o) helped, but lead to another issue. The bash scripts use relative paths eg.. quo1342-134217728-t3a.xlarge.sh contains references like

```
../../dist/v0.1.0-alpha/unix/mjolnir
```

when I use your script it runs, but it appears that the execution does not respect the file path in the script i.e

```
 ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known + ../../dist/v0.1.0-alpha/unix/mjolnir destroy ../../examples/values-local-549755813888-t3a.xlarge.yaml
```

Is there a way to run the script that doesnt break this

Comment: It is not clear what are the 12 folders name. Can you add one/two folders to the tree ?

Comment: thanks for helping!! I have added the samples of the other folders to the folder ASCII tree .
`.
├── quo1374
├── quo2147
├── quo1407
......
├── quo1342
│   ├── dist`

Comment: @dash-o I have updated this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement with a help function

```
Function run_folder {
   local  dir=$1 f=
   cd $dir/run
   # sequential execution
   for f in */*.sh ; do
       # Execute each test in it's folder.
       (cd ${f%/*} && bash ${f##*/} -H)
   done
}

# parallel execution 
For j in * ; do
   run_folder $j &
Done
wait
```

Comment: I am not I understand the problem. Is there an error message ? What file is printed with the echo

Comment: nevermind was a mistake on my path sorry!!!. I have a real issue now is that the bash scripts use relative paths eg.. `quo1342-134217728-t3a.xlarge.sh` contains references like `../../dist/v0.1.0-alpha/unix/mjolnir` when I use your script it runs, but it appears that the execution does not respect the file path in the script i.e `ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
+ ../../dist/v0.1.0-alpha/unix/mjolnir destroy ../../examples/values-local-549755813888-t3a.xlarge.yaml` Is there a way to run the script that doesnt break this?

Comment: updated question and upvoted. This issue prevents me from accepting it as I cannot be 100% sure that it works . Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: @dash-o : Perhaps it would make sense to have a safety net for the case that there are really plenty of folders, to avoid getting too many parallel processes.

Comment: @user1934428 I agree. The question specified 12 folders, but no information about time resources to run each test. Assuming test are not resource intensive, 12 concurrent jobs should not be an issue. To scale up xargs/parallel should be used.

Comment: @SamuelDare I've tried to mimic the 'cd' that was used in the question, implying the script should be executed from quo1342/run. I believe you want each *.sh to be executed with pwd=locaton of *.sh. Proposed solution modified to reflect this requirement

Comment: Thanks alot for your continued support @dash-o. Unfortunately it doesnt seem to execute the scripts. The output can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Genysys/e5190fc76b5b353f53cb2c37719c5767. Any other ideas? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: and yes my requirement was ` I believe you want each *.sh to be executed with pwd=locaton of *.sh. Proposed solution modified to reflect this requirement ` @dash-o

Comment: @dash-o : Also, your `bash $f` won't work, because you are already in the directory of the script, but `f` contains also the directory name. You should do a `bash $(basename $f)` instead.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks for catching this one. I've modified to just basename (using bash prefix removal, instead of basename). Either works fine.

Comment: Happy we could help :-)

Comment: @dash-o : While your solution is correct for the particular case of the OP (where the scripts are one directory level deep below the PWD), I suggest that you use for getting the basename `${f##*/}` instead of `${f#*/}`, since this would work in the general case.